# Change class of just one element in an ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I have an ng-repeat. And I would like to change the class of just that element vs the entire group.

```
<button ng-class="defaultClass" ng-repeat="tube in node.Tubes" ng-click="toggleBtn(tube)">{{"Tube " + ($index + 1)}}</button>
```

with the above HTML on my `ng-click` I can pass the tube, which really only gives me the data passed from the API, if I `console.log(this)` I see the class name in an element called `$$watchers` but that seems odd to change it from there.

```
$scope.toggleBtn = function (element) {
    console.log(element);
    console.log(this);
}
```

In my controller I have `$scope.defaultClass = "btn btn-off";` but if I change that with the function it changes every element.

How can I only change the class of the element clicked?

Comment: Is that what you wanted to do: http://plnkr.co/edit/WKLJ45yRYu1583C2ZnfT ?

Comment: close, I need it to toggle

Comment: plus I need a different class when they are loaded, which is what I was trying to do with `$scope.defaultClass`

Comment: is toggled class the same for all buttons?

Comment: basically they need to load with 'btn btn-off' then when clicked just that element changes to 'btn btn-on'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Continuing from the comments. Than you can't use $scope variable for that, because, as you said, it will be the same. TO solve this you need to use ng-class properly.
Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass (see an example at the bottom of the page)

```
<button ng-class="{'btn-on' : tube.toggled, 'btn-off' : !tube.toggled}" ng-repeat="tube in node.Tubes" ng-click="toggleBtn(tube)">{{"Tube " + ($index + 1)}}</button>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/WKLJ45yRYu1583C2ZnfT?p=preview

Comment: I have a similar problem, but I need the selected button toggles back to their previous class when clicking a different item..

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I understand if that's what you want, but you can use:

```
<button class="btn" ng-repeat="tube in node.Tubes" ng-class="{'btn-off':!toggled, 'btn-on':toggled}" ng-click="toggled = !toggled">{{"Tube " + ($index + 1)}}</button>
```

no need to add any code to the controller in this case.

Answer (score 1):

These other answers are excellent. However, I would like to point out another method for this. Let's say you were looping through an array of receipts. For example, in the controller you had receipts in scope:

```
$scope.receipts = [ ... ];
```

And on the front-end you were looping through these receipts:

```
<div ng-repeat="receipt in receipts">{{ receipt.[attribute] }}</div>
```

One way to keep track of unique classes is to add a "class" key to the receipt objects. For example a receipt would look like:

```
receipt { 'id': '1', 'class' : ' ... ' }
```

On the front-end, you would determine the class using ng-class:

```
<div ng-repeat="receipt in receipts">
     <div ng-class="receipt.class"></div>
</div>
```

And then, you could pass the receipt and its ID to a toggleButton() method like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="receipt in receipts">
     <div class="btn" ng-click="toggleClass(receipt.id)"></div>
     <div ng-class="receipt.class"></div>
</div>
```

And then within the controller you could simply update the class for that particular receipt (assuming here there is a method getReceipt() that gets a receipt from the array $scope.receipts):

```
$scope.toggleClass = function(id) {
     getReceipt(id).class = { ... }
}
```

This would dynamically change the class for that single receipt based on the logic within the toggleClass() function.